# ASP.NET MVC - Compare an end date with a start date with the start date already saved in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, repository

My system will work as follows:
I have a start date and an end date.
When you make a appointment, it inserts the start date and saves this data. When making a new appointment the user should put the end date of that last appointment.

My question is how I would compare this final date that he entered, with the star date already in the bank.

My idea is that the end date is not less than or equal to the star date

```
 I tried that way, but it will not work because I'm not picking the last start date in the dataBase to compare

public class finalDateoftheAppointmentCannotbeLessthantheStartDate : ISpecification<Appointment>
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(InfoAppointment  infoAppointment)
    {
        return infoAppointment.EndDate<= infoApontamento.StarDate;
    }
}
```

Im using repositorys:

Thats my repository class, maybe we can search the last date here to compare

```
   public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Buscar(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Dbset.Where(predicate);
    }

public class InfoApontamentosRepository : Repository<InfoAppointment>, IAppointmentRepository
{
    public InfoAppointmentRepository(RveContext rveContext) : base(rveContext)
    {
    }

    public InfoAppointment FindLastStartDate(Date date)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //example
     public InfoApontamento FindByNumber(int number)
    {
        return Buscar(c => c.Atendimento == number).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

To summarize: How can I get the last initial date saved in the database and compare with the end date entered by the user to prevent the end date being less than or equal to the starting date

Comment: Typically, you would do a query on the date, in descending order, then take the first record to get the oldest date/time.

Comment: Any example how i can do that?

Comment: Somewhat like `return Buscar(condition).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).FirstOrDefault()`. However without knowing which context containing start date property, it's hard to tell exact implementation; please add more details about the context you're using and how you want to check both dates somewhere.